# Yield return does not work properly? - Unity Game development C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, button, game-development

so I am programming a game and for my main menu I created a button with which one can delete the highscore.
After pressing the "DeleteHighscore" Button, a "Confirm" button pops up, which I implemented with the  "OnClick" method in Unity itself. After confirming, the successfullyDeleted Text appears, because of another OnClick method, but it does not disappear. Right now, everything disappears and I just get a blue screen after confirming, but nothing disappears when I change it to "successfullyDeleted.SetActive(false);"
Here is the code I tried using:

```
public void DeleteHighscore()
{
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt(" highscore ", 0); 
    StartCoroutine(HideTextAfterDelay(5)); 
  
    gameObject.SetActive(false); 

}

IEnumerator HideTextAfterDelay(float delay) 
{  
    Debug.Log("HideTextAfterDelay called with delay: " + delay);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay); 
     
}`
```

I tried to create the gameobject "public GameObject successfullyDeleted;"
and changed the line "gameObject.SetActive(false); " to "successfullyDeleted.SetActive(false);"
Unfortunately, it does not work, although I dragged the gameobject into the script in the unity inspector.

Comment: `gameObject.SetActive(false); ` If you deactivate the object that is running coroutines then any coroutines running on it stop. The coroutine you've shown also does nothing other than print a log. Perhaps you want `gameObject.SetActive(false);` inside it to run after the delay?

Comment: So like that? `public void DeleteHighscore()
    
    {
      
      PlayerPrefs.SetInt(" highscore ", 0);  
      StartCoroutine(HideTextAfterDelay(5f));

    }

 
      IEnumerator HideTextAfterDelay(float delay)
{
    Debug.Log("HideTextAfterDelay called with delay: " + delay);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);

    gameObject.SetActive(false);
    Debug.Log("Hiding game object");`

Comment: I fixed it! I changed it to ´yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(delay);´ and now it works! Thanks for your help though, I appreciate it, since I also put the ´gameObject.SetActive(false);´ line into the HideTextAfterDelay method!

Answer (score 0):

You could add a `Debug.Log` in your coroutine to check if the coroutine is being triggered correctly. If the coroutine is triggered and the `Debug.Log` is being shown in the *Debug Console* in *Unity*, you could try to modify the coroutine to hide the `succesfullyDeleted` directly instead of using `SetActive(false)`.

I added a `Debug.Log` in your coroutine for you and i modified the coroutine to hide the object directly. Hope this helps you solve the problem:

```
public GameObject successfullyDeleted;

public void DeleteHighscore()
{
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("highscore", 0);
    StartCoroutine(HideTextAfterDelay(5));
}

IEnumerator HideTextAfterDelay(float delay)
{
    Debug.Log("HideTextAfterDelay called with delay: " + delay);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);
    
    successfullyDeleted.SetActive(false);
}
```